# How do I get just the hours, minutes, and seconds, but separately?

Tags: python

```
print("Enter your start time!")
time1h = int(input("Hour: "))
time1m = int(input("Minute: "))
time1s = int(input("Second: "))
print("Enter your finishing time!")
time2h = int(input("Hour: "))
time2m = int(input("Minute: "))
time2s = int(input("Second: "))

time1 = datetime.time(time1h,time1m,time1s)
time2 = datetime.time(time2h,time2m,time2s)

diff = datetime.timedelta(hours=(time2.hour - time1.hour), minutes=(time2.minute - time1.minute), seconds=(time2.second - time1.second))
print(diff)
```

I am trying to print the results from the diff variable separately from each other so I can format it like
"You ran for (diffhours) hours, (diffminutes) minutes, and (diffseconds) seconds"

Comment: `print(f"You ran for {diff.seconds//3600} hours, {diff.seconds//60 % 60} minutes and {diff.seconds % 60} seconds")`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While you can use `diff.seconds` and then carry out various calculations to convert it to hours and minutes as suggested in the other answers, it's also possible to convert `diff` to a string and process it that way:

```py
diff = str(diff).split(':') # diff will be something like 1:01:23
print(f'You ran for {diff[0]} hours, {diff[1]} minutes and {diff[2]} seconds')
```

Example output:

```
You ran for 1 hours, 01 minutes and 01 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could do something like this

```
output_string = str(diff).split(':')
print("You ran for {} hours, {} minutes, and {} seconds".format(*output_string))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code:

```
print("Enter your start time!")
time1h = int(input("Hour: "))
time1m = int(input("Minute: "))
time1s = int(input("Second: "))
print("Enter your finishing time!")
time2h = int(input("Hour: "))
time2m = int(input("Minute: "))
time2s = int(input("Second: "))

time1 = timedelta(hours=time1h, minutes=time1m, seconds=time1s)
time2 = timedelta(hours=time2h, minutes=time2m, seconds=time2s)
diff = time2-time1

total_sec = diff.total_seconds()
h = int(total_sec // 3600)
total_sec = total_sec % 3600
m = int(total_sec // 60)
s = int(total_sec % 60)

print(f"You ran for {h} hours, {m} minutes, and {s} seconds")
```

Comment: you can import timedelta by the following command: from datetime import timedelta